# SQLite3 Python inserting multiple lists

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm working on Natural language toolkit for my native language. I want to create new database using SQLite3.
I made empty table with 4 columns. There are 4 lists containing data for each column.

Among many variants I tried following:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
with conn:
 cur = conn.cursor()
 for i in range(len(dataTxt)):
    dataList = (L1[i], L2[i], L3[i], L4[i])

    sql = ''' INSERT INTO new_table(col1, col2, col3, col4)
                                         VALUES(?,?,?,?)'''                
    cur.execute(sql, dataList )
```

*Where L1 holds ints and L2- L4 strings,
but get error:

> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: L1 presumably holds values of a type that can't be converted to sqlite ones.

Comment: @Shawn it contains int

Comment: That type would not result in the error message shown. What is `type(L1[i])`?

Answer (score 0):

```
cur.execute(sql, (L1[i],...,L4[i]) )
```

worked  within `for` cycle.

Apparently `.execute` only takes two values.